# I have downloaded laravel project but it has no artisan file in root directory

Tags: laravel

I have downloaded laravel project from friends website but it has no artisan file in the root directory.

When I run `php artisan list` it gives an error:

> could not open input file: artisan

[image]

Comment: which installation method did you use? the composer method is consistent and you will need composer anyways

Comment: By composer i have installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pull it from [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel?files=1), and test with `php artisan`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use *`php artisan`* if you are not inside your downloaded Laravel project folder. That is why you got an error `could not open input file artisan`

Go to your project directory using *`cd`* command in your command prompt For example: *`cd YourProjectName`*, Now you will be able to run *`php artisan list`* or *`php artisan`* it will display you list of all available commands.

**NOTE:** If you need Laravel installation then don't download the project on other websites. Always prefer the [official document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7#installing-laravel) for installation.

Comment: now it gives me that error. Warning: require(D:\xampp\htdocs\upload\vendor\composer/../guzzlehttp/promises/src/functions_include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\upload\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66

Comment: @SoldeirX run in your command prompt `composer require guzzlehttp/promises`

Comment: Declaration of App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::boot() should be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider::boot()

Comment: @SoldeirX please check here: [Link](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php#L28-L33) Have your configuration according to this?

Comment: Try `composer install && composer dump-autoload && php artisan cache:clear` in your cli aswell

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but most people's errors are once they download the project, they need to go to the folder they named the project. For example:
`C:/laravelPrjects`

Then you run your terminal in this folder like this:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel New-Project
```

Here it is that you need to go to the folder created for the project
by typing `cd New-Project` and you end like this:
`C:/laravelPrjects/New-Project`

I hope this helps somebody. Most of the time, people who are pros in this, don't have time to help, and it is good to share what we know